# Performance tuning the hierarchydata in SQL

Tags: sql, query-optimization

Hi I have places list of a temp table **#tmpPlaceGroupData** like below

```
    Place                 Complete_PlaceId
----------------------------------------
India                 1
  Maharashtra         1|MH
     Sangli           1|MH|SA
       Sangli_A       1|MH|SA|SA_A
       Sangli_B       1|MH|SA|SA_B
     Akola            1|MH|AK
       Akola_A        1|MH|AK|AK_A
       Akola_B        1|MH|AK|AK_B
     Aurangabad       1|MH|AU
 Telangana            1|TG
    Adilabad          1|TG|AD
       Adilabad_A     1|TG|AD|AD_A
       Adilabad_B     1|TG|AD|AD_B
    Karimnagar        1|TG|KA
    Nizamabad         1|TG|NZ
 AndhraPradesh        1|AP
   Krishna            1|AP|KR 
   Guntur             1|AP|GU
   Nellore            1|AP|NE
```

User can save the place at Country Level , State level , District level or Village level, this saved IDs will be inserted into **#tblPlaceDataInserted**, Now if the user saved at State level(eg: Maharashtra) I need to remove all the childs under that state(Sangli(2 villages), Akola(2 villages), Aurangabad(1)). I wrote below query to do a delete

```
delete T
FROM #tmpPlaceGroupData AS T
INNER JOIN #tblPlaceDataInserted AS E ON iif(left(T.Complete_PlaceId, LEN(E.CompletePlaceID) + 1) = E.CompletePlaceID + '|', 1, 0) = 1
```

It is taking around 20 , 25 seconds to this statement get executed, data we have in **#tmpPlaceGroupData** is around 50k+ records. Is there any other ways to improve the performance for this query?

Comment: This looks like product-specific code, probably t-sql? If so have you considered using supported [hierarchy data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "...if the user saved...I need to remove all the childs...". Do you mean that if the user deleted (not saved) at state level then you need to delete all the children?

Comment: @NickW I will actually have to remove childs under any level , to avoid junk data / duplicate data insert again and again into main tables .

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but I was really questioning your use of the word "saved" and whether you really meant "deleted"? If you delete a parent record I can understand the need to delete orphaned child records. If you don't mean "deleted" then what does "saved" mean (added, changed, deleted)? If you add/change a parent record why would you need to delete child records?